# Xtext: Return a predefined literal value with a rule

Tags: xtext

Let's say I have a rule `Property`:

```
Property:
    key=ID '=' value=ID;
```

And a source text file that looks like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Now I want the parser to substitute every key `c` with `d` so that the parsed result would be:

```
({a=1}, {b=2}, {d=3})
```

I have searched SO and the [Xtext doc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.xtext.doc%2Fcontents%2Fxtext.html&cp=70) but can't find anything. So my question is: can I return a predefined literal value with a rule?

Comment: i dont get this question. you want to do a model 2 model transformation on the parsed model. if such a thing is done then the model is ususally enriched (using a derivedstatecomputer) or do you simply want "if i type c then d should be read"

Comment: @ChristianDietrich The latter, I want the parser to set a different value of key when the rule is matched.

Comment: Have a look at dataype rules and value converters